# Quitar digitos de un DATETIME en Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo una query ne la cual ingreso fechas  , pero me los arroja con este tipo de datos y solo quiero que me arroje la variable con fechas y no con hras

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   Finicio = fields.txtFInicio
    Ftermino = fields.txtFTermino

    Q = "EXEC [dbo].[SP_NI_Perfiles_UsuariosXPerfil_I] ";
```

Comment: por favor agrega con la consultas, de otro modo hay como ayudarte

Comment: Si lo que quieres es extraer los primeros 10 dígitos del string, prueba usando el método `substring(0,10)`. Eso te debe devolver `"03/26/2019"` para el primer caso. Podrías hacerlo como `Finicio = fields.txtFinicio.substring(0, 10);`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion split

```
const fechaSeparada=fechaInicio.split(" "); //esto genera un arreglo, en este caso de 3 valores, la fecha, la hora y el AM

const fecha=fechaSeparada[0]; //Aqui almacenas solo la fecha que es lo que te interesa, la cual esta en la posicion 0 del arreglo que generó el split
```

Espero te sirva. Un saludo.